# How to move the files to Trash Bin from asp.net site?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a asp.net site. User login and can select some files from backend, then click a button to delete these files. Now we want to send these files to system trash bin.

Here is what I did:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.DeleteFile(
    filename,
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs,
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin,
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UICancelOption.ThrowException);
```

it works fine when use this code in the console program, however, when I use this in the asp.net site, it deletes the files, but not send to Trash Bin.

Is it because of permission? Any way to send files to Trash Bin in asp.net site?

Thanks

Comment: Trash bin for non-interactive account? I don't think one exists... You may want to look into that.

Comment: I would create a "recycle bin" folder in the website and move files to that. Then if you really need them in the real Windows bin you could create a Windows Service or Console App as Scheduled Task that removes files from that folder.

Comment: Yes, I agree - make your own folder - move files to that folder. That way, you don't mess  with the server stuff . Maybe the admin will make a few changes - empty recycle bin, and your files will be gone. So I would simple make your own delete folder and move files to that folder.

Comment: thanks, looks like it is a good suggestion. @VDWWD , if you create an answer, I'll accept it.